# How to hide google sheet token in c# application?

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api, credentials

Im working with google sheet API with C# WinForms app using VS2017. The code is working fine. But at this point of code:

```
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
```

It asks for credentials, chrome pops up, ask for user authentication and now token.json file is created for the first time. I want to take token.json file and embedded in my .exe file as Embedded resource. So that it no longer visible to clients. Let me know what code changes need to be made.